# Other compression methods for Federated Learning

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I noticed that the Gradient Quantization compression method is already implemented in TFF framework. How about non-traditional compression methods where we select a sub-model by dropping some parts of the global model? I come across the "Federated Dropout" compression method in the paper "Expanding the Reach of Federated Learning by Reducing Client Resource Requirements" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.07210). Any idea if Federated Dropout method is already supported in Tensorflow Federated. If not, any insights how to implement it (the main idea of the method is dropping a fixed percentage of the activations and filters in the global model to exchange and train a smaller sub-model)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no implementation of this idea available in the TFF code base.

But here is an outline of how you could do it, I recommend to start from [`examples/simple_fedavg`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/v0.16.1/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg)

1. Modify top-level [`build_federated_averaging_process`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/1dedbe4d91281a210098daa230b0cb0aa8d6a339/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L54) to accept two `model_fn`s -- one `server_model_fn` for the global model, one `client_model_fn` for the smaller sub-model structure actually trained on clients.
2. Modify [`build_server_broadcast_message`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/1dedbe4d91281a210098daa230b0cb0aa8d6a339/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L173) to extract only the relevant sub-model from the `server_state.model_weights`. This would be the mapping from server model to client model.
3. The [`client_update`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/1dedbe4d91281a210098daa230b0cb0aa8d6a339/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L192) may actually not need to be changed (I am not 100% sure), as long as only the `client_model_fn` is provided from [`client_update_fn`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/1dedbe4d91281a210098daa230b0cb0aa8d6a339/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L103).
4. Modify [`server_update`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/1dedbe4d91281a210098daa230b0cb0aa8d6a339/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L139) - the `weights_delta` will be the update to the client sub-model, so you will need to map it back to the larger global model.

In general, the steps 2. and 4. are tricky, as they depend not only what layers are in a model, but also the how they are connected. So it will be hard to create a easy to use general solution, but it should be ok to write these for a specific model structure you know in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the insights.

Comment: With respect to the sketched solution, I would like to know (and ask) whether and how is it possible to account for different sub-models (i.e., same sub-model architecture but randomly "composed" considering differently dropped filters/neurons for each client) since tff.federated_broadcast just sends the same message (i.e., the same model weights) to each client -- in the above outline happens in point (2). A similar problem I think may arise from collecting back differently mapped sub-models, point (4). Any advice on this front would be very important and useful to me.

Comment: You can broadcast the whole model and perform the selection at CLIENTS, independently for each of them. How exactly should they be combined together again is not clear to me, I can see multiple variants to this, and don't know what makes most sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I implemented it as you seggested, directly at CLIENTS. With respect to your last point about aggregation: when combining the clients' weights delta resulting from different sub-models, should they only contribute for the related sub-model parameters, hence should I have to implement an ad-hoc aggregation? I mean if I map back the sub-model weights delta to the global model by filling with zeros the dropped filters/connections, the federated mean would be (incorrectly) spoiled by such zeros afterwards, or am I wrong? I was not able to retrieve this info in the mentioned paper.

Answer (score 0):

We have several compression schemas implemented in our simulator:

*"FL_PyTorch: Optimization Research Simulator for Federated Learning."*

https://burlachenkok.github.io/FL_PyTorch-Available-As-Open-Source/
https://github.com/burlachenkok/flpytorch

FL_PyTorch is a suite of open-source software written in python that builds on top of one of the most popular research Deep Learning (DL) frameworks PyTorch. We built FL_PyTorch as a research simulator for FL to enable fast development, prototyping, and experimenting with new and existing FL optimization algorithms. Our system supports abstractions that provide researchers with sufficient flexibility to experiment with existing and novel approaches to advance the state-of-the-art. The work is in proceedings of the 2nd International Workshop on Distributed Machine Learning DistributedML 2021. The paper, presentation, and appendix are available in DistributedML’21 Proceedings (https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3488659.3493775).